# SSL Exception: error:1409E10F:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:bad length

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, network-programming, poco-libraries

I'm using the [Poco](https://pocoproject.org/) libraries to write a networked application, specifically built around `Poco::Net::SecureStreamSocket`. Some users have lately begun reporting that they're seeing the following error:

`SSL Exception: error:1409E10F:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:bad length`

This seems like a very easily Google-able error, but for some reason I can't find a lot of good information about what I'm doing wrong. From what I've gleaned, it seems as though this error indicates that there was an SSL renegotiation under the hood (?) and the underlying SSL library needs the client (i.e. me) to retransmit data. However, as near as I can tell all previous messages were transmitted successfully.

The code that's catching the exception looks like this:

```
try
    {
        if (!m_socket)
        {
            return false;
        }

        int32_t res = m_socket->sendBytes((uint8_t*)header, send_len);
        if (res != send_len)
        {
            // Handle error
        }

        res = m_socket->sendBytes(item->buffer.data(), item->buffer.size());
        if (res != (int32_t)item->buffer.size())
        {
            // Handle error
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (const Poco::IOException& e)
    {
        LOG_ERROR("transmit:IOException: " + e.displayText());
        // Handle error
    }
```

It's the error log inside the exception handler for the `Poco::IOException` which is cluing me in to this issue.

Comment: The "ssl3_write_bytes:bad length" error means that data being received is bad.  I find the  most likely reason for this is that you have broken the openssl multi-threading rules.  The most common problem is that if you overlap the socket reads and writes (which is fine for sockets) can cause the "bad length" problem at random times.  If Poco is not guarding you against this problem then you have to do it in your own code.

Comment: Hi @ShanePowell, thanks for your suggestion! I took another look just to be sure, but all communication with the socket is handled on the same thread. The socket is in blocking mode, so there shouldn't be an opportunity for overlapped I/O. Are there other possible reasons why I might see this error?

Comment: In my experience, no.  Only very unlikely reasons, like corruption of  data during transport.  i.e. the data being sent is not the same as the data being received on the other end.

Comment: @ShanePowell Could it be possible for this error to occur when write returns SSL_WANT_WRITE, and then the code calls read instead? Would that count as an overlapped read / write?

Comment: I'm not sure but most likely.  I assume poco is handling the underlying openssl API.  If that isn't following the required openssl api requirements then you are stuffed...  If it's asking for a write, you have to give a write next (normally of any length, including zero because it wants to do some protocol stuff like renegotiation) .

Comment: Poco passes SSL_WANT_WRITE and SSL_WANT_READ to the client code. My code tries to fulfill its requests, but there are some cases where it could fail to provide the requested I/O.

Comment: So Poco leaves it to the client code to handle it... that seems like a bad idea, but I can see why you are having problems.  You really need to handle the results with the "expected" data.  I think you really need to read the openssl documentation and understand what it's trying to say you need to do.  Look at examples like the openssl utility code.

Comment: You must be in non-blocking mode to get SSL_WANT_WRITE / SSL_WANT_READ.  If you get SSL_WANT_WRITE, you HAVE to call the ssl_write[_ex] function, even with a zero length buffer next.  If you get a SSL_WANT_READ you must wait for more data from socket and call a ssl_read[_ex] function.   This normally means you will need to queue write buffers until you are allowed to "write" again.

Comment: I normally hide behind boost::asio which does all this for me.  What you have to be careful about with boost::asio is threaded access when the io_context is running on multiple threads.

Comment: That's extra weird then, because I'm not in non-blocking mode, unless Poco puts the underlying socket in non-blocking mode even on blocking I/O.

Comment: In OpenSSL is in blocking mode, then it will only return SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ if SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY is turned off.  If you are seeing SSL_WANT_WRITE, then SSL must be in non-blocking mode.  Maybe the poco socket is on blocking mode, but ssl context is in non-blocking mode.

Comment: @ShanePowell plot twist: it looks like an I/O is timing out and then when retrying the I/O I get this error. Do you know if there's a preferred way I should retry a timed-out I/O to avoid hitting this?